# SimplicialLLT returns wrong cholesky factors

Tags: c++, eigen, scientific-computing

I want to use Eigen to compute the cholesky decomposition of a sparse matrix. However, the result is incorrect and I am not able to find a reason for it. How do I get the correct answer?

And are there special routines implemented in Eigen which exploit the structure of sparse matrices in order to boost performance (e.g. for banded matrices as in the example below or triangular matrices)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main() 
{

    // create sparse Matrix
    int n = 5; 
    std::vector<Eigen::Triplet<double> > ijv; 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ijv.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double>(i,i,1));
        if(i < n-1)
        {
            ijv.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double>(i+1,i,-0.9));
        }
    }
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> X(n,n);
    X.setFromTriplets(ijv.begin(), ijv.end());
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> XX = X * X.transpose();

    // Cholesky decomposition 
    Eigen::SimplicialLLT <Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > cholesky;
    cholesky.analyzePattern(XX);
    cholesky.factorize(XX);

    std::cout << Eigen::MatrixXd(XX) << std::endl;
    std::cout << Eigen::MatrixXd(cholesky.matrixL()) << std::endl;

}
```

The matrices look as follows:

Input `XX`:

```
   1 -0.9    0    0    0
-0.9 1.81 -0.9    0    0
   0 -0.9 1.81 -0.9    0
   0    0 -0.9 1.81 -0.9
   0    0    0 -0.9 1.81
```

Output (`cholesky.matrixL()`):

```
  1.34536         0         0         0         0
-0.668965   1.16726         0         0         0
        0 -0.771039    1.1025         0         0
        0         0         0         1         0
        0         0 -0.816329      -0.9  0.577587
```

What it should look like (`X`):

```
   1    0    0    0   0
-0.9    1    0    0   0
   0 -0.9    1    0   0
   0    0 -0.9    1   0
   0    0    0 -0.9   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget that `SimplicialLLT` does not factorize `A = L * L^T` but `P * A * P^T = L * T^T` with `P` a permutation matrix. If you need `P` to be the identity then use `NaturalOrdering`:

```
Eigen::SimplicialLLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, Eigen::Lower, Eigen::NaturalOrdering<int> > cholesky;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Adding `NaturalOrdering` leads to the compile error `error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _MatrixType, int _UpLo, class _Ordering> class Eigen::SimplicialLLT’`. I guess I also have to provide `int _UpLo` to make it work. I tried to find out how to do this in the documentation and it says `the triangular part that will be used for the computations. It can be Lower or Upper. Default is Lower.` but not how to actually add this. Could you please help with this as well?

Comment: Please check the sample code from the answer below.

Comment: Right, there were a typo.

Answer (score 3):

[`SimplicialLLT`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SimplicialLLT.html#ad6e49b1c0d2ec5c8e118538260f3002c) computes the Cholesky decomposition up to a permutation. Using `Eigen::NaturalOrdering` the identity permutation is used and you get the result you expect:

```
Eigen::SimplicialLLT <Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, Eigen::Lower, Eigen::NaturalOrdering<int>> cholesky;
cholesky.compute(XX);
```