# Eigen SimplicialLLT gives incorrect results when called from multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, eigen

I am trying to use SimplicialLLT to compute a SparseMatrix. Since my program runs in a loop and each sparse matrix is different I am trying to parallelize the call to SimplicialLLT as follows. This is not the exact running code. I have tried to duplicate the section where the calls are made.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Eigen/Core"
#include "Eigen/LU"
#include "Eigen/Sparse"
#include "Eigen/StdVector"
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

#define NROW 4

void subProg1(int ii, int nodes);
using namespace std;


int main()
{
  int imax = 4;
  int ii, nodes;

  std::thread threadpointer[4];

  nodes = 20000;

  for (ii=0;ii<imax;ii++) {
    threadpointer[ii] = std::thread(subProg1,ii,nodes);
    //threadpointer[ii].join();
  }

  for (ii=0;ii<imax;ii++) {
    threadpointer[ii].join();
  }
    

}

void subProg1(int IROW, int nodes)
{
  static vector<SparseMatrix<double>> Kmat(NROW, SparseMatrix<double> (nodes*3,nodes*3));
  static vector<SimplicialLLT<SparseMatrix<double>>> Kmat_LLT(Kmat.size());
  
  //Asign Kmat values here
  //Kmat[IROW] = ....
  
  //Invert Kmat using SimplicialLLT
  cout<< " Before Kmat_LLT IROW :" <<IROW<<endl;
  Kmat_LLT[IROW].compute(Kmat[IROW]);
  cout<< " After Kmat_LLT IROW:" <<IROW<<endl;

}
```

The results that I get when joining the thread immediately after the call to subProg1 is different when the threads are joined in a separate loop after all the calls to subProg1. I am trying to determine why this is happening. The cout statement shows the following

when the thread is joined immediately after the call (essentially this is running without multi-threading)

```
before Kmat_LLT IROW: 0
after Kmat_LLT IROW: 0
before Kmat_LLT IROW: 1
after Kmat_LLT IROW: 1
before Kmat_LLT IROW: 2
after Kmat_LLT IROW: 2
before Kmat_LLT IROW: 3
after Kmat_LLT IROW: 3
```

When subProg1 is called as part of multi threading and joined after all calls are complete

```
before Kmat_LLT IROW : 3
before Kmat_LLT IROW: 0
before Kmat_LLT IROW: 1
before Kmat_LLT IROW: 2
after Kmat_LLT IROW : 2
after Kmat_LLT IROW: 0
after Kmat_LLT IROW: 1
after Kmat_LLT IROW: 3
```

I am not sure why the results of Kmat_LLT[IROW] are different between both methods. Wondering if something in incorrect with the declaration of Kmat_LLT in subProg1. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wondering is anyone has any thoughts on what could be wrong here. Not sure if simplicialLLT should be declared in a different way

Comment: If anyone can help me with this request I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What compiler are you using? You use static variables for the results. Those are initialized the first time the function runs. That is inside one of the threads. Depending on the compiler, this might not be safe from race-conditions.

Comment: @Homer512 I am using VS2017. Although I am using static arrays to store the results, they are based on IROW which would be unique for each call (thread) to subProg1. My understanding is this will not cause a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues here. There's no reason to believe those print statements should appear in order if you're calling subProg1 concurrently.

Do you mean that the contents of the Cholesky factorizations are different depending on how you're calling it? That could be a problem, but it also could be an issue of the permutation matrix- this function factorizes the input with potentially permuted rows and columns- you can [specify that the original ordering is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225371/simplicialllt-returns-wrong-cholesky-factors), and that would solve that issue. There are a number of reasons why it might end up giving different permutation matrices that depend on the specifics of the algorithm but it's altogether not important so long as you take it into account.

Comment: Yes. depending on how SImplicialLLT is called the contents of the Cholesky factorizations are different.  I tried to add NaturalOrdering as you suggested. However it makes the computation take a very very long time to the point where single threaded calls are much faster without specifying the ordering scheme.

Comment: Also if I apply a mutex lock to the computation ```Kmat_LLT[IROW].compute(Kmat[IROW]);``` then the results are consistent.

Comment: Is it possible that your input matrices are sharing memory? Easy way to check would be to make a (deep) copy of each before calling the decomposition. Since the results are consistent when you use a mutex I don't expect that this will help but it's a good sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may not actually be with the computation. It is with std::cout. C++ streams are only threadsafe withing a single call. All your threads try to write to cout at the same time and start stumbling over each other, potentially completing each other's lines. There are two simple solutions:

1. Put everything that should appear together on screen (i.e. a full line) into a single printf.
2. Put everything into a std::ostringstream first, then write the ostringstream to cout in a single operation.

In C++20 you could use synchronized output streams instead.
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0053r0.html