# How to declare an array of eigen sparse matrices

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I would like to know if the following declaration of eigen sparse matrix is
correct

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Eigen/Core"
#include "Eigen/LU"
#include "Eigen/Sparse"
#include "Eigen/StdVector"
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

#define NROW 20 
#define NODES 20000

vector<SparseMatrix<double>> Kmat(NROW, SparseMatrix<double> (NODES,NODES));
```

The Kmat for every NROW will be inverted for which I am using SimplicialLLT
cholesky decomposition method and this is how I am declaring it

```
 static vector<SimplicialLLT<SparseMatrix<double>>> Kmat_LLT(Kmat.size());
```

Basically I would like to store each inverted matrix corresponding to NROW
such that it can be used later. Wondering if the above declaration of Kmat_LLT
is correct. The code does compile and run.

Comment: Well, if the compiler does not complain and the code does what you expect it to do, I'd dare say: Yes, your declaration is correct.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium the issue is when I call SimplicialLLT from multiple threads the results are not what I expect. That makes me wonder if Kmat_LLT is getting overwritten from other NROW sparse matrices. I have explained this issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69729481/eigen-simplicialllt-gives-incorrect-results-when-called-from-multiple-threads.